# How to check if a key exists in a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby

I am using search of Net::LDAP, the returned entry is something like this.

```
#<Net::LDAP::Entry:0x7f47a6491c00
 @myhash=
  {:loginshell=>["/bin/bash"],
   :cn=>["M... R..."],
   :homedirectory=>["/mnt/home/m..."],
   :uid=>["m..."],
   :userpassword=>["{CRYPT}$1$3zR/C...$R1"],
   ...
}>
```

I tried to do the following, but failed.

(1)

```
e = entry.to_hash
e.has_key? "uid"
```

(2)

```
entry.has_key? "uid"
```

The first error says "to_hash" undefined, the second "has_key" undefined. Then I really don't know how to do it, basically I want to find if "uid" is present and if so get its correspondent value.

Thank you very much for the tip.

BTW, it only responds to "entry.uid", but if the search key is provided as a string, how to do that? for example,

```
def get_value(key)
  if entry has key 
    return key's value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`:uid` is a `Symbol`. That's not a `String`.

try this:

```
e.has_key? :uid
```

Comment: If all you have is a string, you could also `"uid".to_sym`

Comment: "has_key" not defined, but "to_sym" is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `has_key?` -be aware of the question mark- is a method of any instance of `Hash` class. It can not be undefined unless you're using it something different than a `Hash` instance.

Comment: That's why I puzzled, I don't know what it is. I end up using "entry.each do |k, v|" to break into key-value pair.

Comment: It's as simple as adding a `.class` to any object to know it's class type. Do a `e.class` and you'll see what it is.

Answer (score 6):

The key "uid" doesn't exist. Try

```
e = Entry.new.myhash
e.has_key?(:uid)
```

That should return true. If that gives you an error, the problem might lie in your class. Make sure that myhash is defined in the initialize method, and that you use a getter method (or attr_reader) to be able to access the variable. You could use

```
attr_reader :myhash
```

right before the initialize method.